# How to get value of Hidden Field Based on Checkbox jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-3.0

I want to print a DIV from hidden field value and I have checkboxes too.

This is my jQuery function:

```
<script>
    $(".printme").click(function () {
        var printArray = [];
        $("input[name='s_i_width[]']:checked").each(function (event) {
            printArray.push($('#form_te' + this.value).val());

            console.log($('#form_te' + this.value).val());

            alert("selected" + printArray);
            console.log(printArray);

            var printselect;
            printselect = printArray.join(',') + "";
            alert("selected" + printselect);
        });
    })
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="form_te<?php echo  $id;?>"value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
```

if it is like this

```
//  printArray.push($(this).val());
```

I can get the values, but if I put like this:

```
printArray.push($('#form_te'+this.value).val());
```

I get an undefined error.

Comment: This isn't even valid javascript because you have `if(...) { else { ... }` there with a missing `}` before the `else`.

Comment: i just edited thanks for showing it

Comment: Please also fix the code indentation, I have a hard time trying to understand what is in which scope and where blocks begin and end...

Comment: You shouldn't use this.value on a checkbox, what is it you are trying to get? you can get this.checked, or you can get the innerHTML.

Comment: how to do that using innerHTML?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML instead of php